# Instructions for building OpenJDK

Tags: jvm, java

I want to build my own JVM and can't find any instructions for doing it on an operating system that is still supported... like one that still receives security updates. I've found [1] very helpful, but it advises building on Fedora 11 or other operating systems from the 2009 era.  What platforms are other JVM hackers using today, and are there any instructions/blogs/best practices out there somewhere for building on newer operating systems?

[1] - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u4/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html

Comment: Have you tried the instructions at all on your new distro? What are the problems that you are having after following them?

Comment: Yes, I've tried.  Lots of cryptic compilation errors.  I can post them when I'm at my dev box, if you think it would help to post them.

Comment: Posting some of the errors in the question would help, as would searching for them on Google. I've never built the Open JDK but currently your question is too broad for anybody to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the package definitions of OpenJDK packages in any of the distributions, they all contain the necessary steps to compile it.

For example, to look at the Ubuntu package, go to [the site of the source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/openjdk-7), download the files at the bottom, extract them, apply the patch and look at the files in the `debian` subdirectory (especially in `debian/rules`).

For the Gentoo package, I guess the relevant ebuild is [this one](https://overlays.gentoo.org/proj/java/browser/java-overlay/dev-java/icedtea/icedtea-7.2.2.1.ebuild).

Comment: How did you find http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/openjdk-7.Did you use the `apt-get` to discover those?

Comment: @sholsapp I already knew the package name and the site http://packages.ubuntu.com, so this was easy. In general you can use `apt-cache search` or a tool like `aptitude` or `synaptic` for searching packages.